# MATLAB: Assign a vector to a multidimensional cell array

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array with data.
I have a 17x10x1024 empty cell array:

```
C=cell(length(data(1,:)),10,1024);

 % length(data(1,:) = 17
```

Then I am calculating (in a while loop (17 times) ) vectors which are 1024x1:

```
value = data(:,i) + randn(size(t))*noise_out;
```

Now I want to assign the values of this vectors to the array, in such a way that:

```
'Name of Signal'                 []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
    'in1'               [1024x1 double]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
    'out1'              [1024x1 double]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
    'in2'               [1024x1 double]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
    'out2'              [1024x1 double]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
    'in3'               [1024x1 double]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
    'out3'              [1024x1 double]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
    'in4'               [1024x1 double]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
    'out4'              [1024x1 double]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
    'in5'               [1024x1 double]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
    'out5'              [1024x1 double]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
    'in6'               [1024x1 double]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
    'out6'              [1024x1 double]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
    'in7'               [1024x1 double]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
    'out7'              [1024x1 double]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
    'in8'               [1024x1 double]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
    'out8'              [1024x1 double]    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []
```

I use the following:

```
C(i,2,:) = {value};

% i is the number of loop from 2 to 17
```

,but the problem is that I literally get a string '[1024x1 double]' instead the real values of the vectors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to get seems not really reasonable to me, because you have a lot of single values in cells, where you'd rather work with vectors.

I'd propose three options:

```
C=cell(length(data(1,:)),10);
C(i,2) = value;
```

which gives you a cell matrix with your names in one column and cells with your signal vectors in the other columns

But actually I'd recommend not to store the names and signals together in a cell array. So keep the names separate and create, if you want a 3D-matrix with your signals:

```
C = zeros(length(data(1,:)),10,1024);
C(i,2,:) = value;
```

or think about using a struct;

```
signal(1).name = 'in1'
signal(1).values = value
signal(2).name = 'out1'
signal(2).values = value2
```

These are all just ideas, and I haven't tried them out, as you not provided enough informations.